# Changing html control input type time format on demand

Tags: html

I want to use `<input type="time">` control. The documentation states that "format depending on operating system locale". Is there a way to change the format on demand?

Comment: You can check the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time for input type time.

Comment: I checked the documentation. The question if there is a way to do so.

Comment: Change formatting as in user can control? Or dependent on local time? Or standardizing across browsers?

Comment: Site supports Multilanguage and user can switch to language of their choice. If they choose English (US) I want the picker to be AM/PM. If they choose English(UK) I want picker to be 24 format.